# Background Image not showing in react production app, showing normally in development

Tags: reactjs, image, create-react-app, production

I have a component 'Countries' that shows a list of countries. It loops a JSON object with country names and paths to their flag images, then passes those as props to a Component 'SingleCountry' who in turn displays them.

Relevant part of component 'Countries':

```
//this is inside return() statement

  <div className="country-list">
            {
                _.map(countries[region], (value, key)=>{
                    const picture = require(`../../img/flags/${value.picPath}`);
                    return(
                    <SingleCountry name={value.name} picture = {picture} countryId={key} key={key} 
                       region={region}/>
                    )
                })
                
            }
            </div>
```

Relevant part of the component 'SingleCountry':

```
//this is inside return() statement
<div className="single-country">
          <div className="flag" style ={{backgroundImage: `url(${picture})`}}></div>
            
            <div className="country-name">{name}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The above is working well in development. You can see a picture here (along with the inspection):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBd66.jpg

However, it is not working in production. You can see a picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/smd9e.jpg

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try adding other css property to that div, let say `color: "red"` as to test whether the server get update or not? As I can see, it doesn't have the background-image to begin with

Comment: There is already a number of CSS properties applied to that div, I am not sure how clear they are but I included them in the snapshot pictures above. Do you mean to try and apply them through js to test? I realize it doesn't have the background-image in production - that is kind of my problem, why it isn't there?

Comment: Well it's true that there is already some CSS property applied to it, but it's through the CSS class. What I mean is, can you add some inline CSS onto that `div` ? Like `color: "red"`